# How to implement subclass constructor of abstract base class?

Tags: c++, clion

So, I have a UML Diagram to follow, and have implemented most of the Exam class, however I run into two issues,

[image: UML Digram]

Issue # 1:

```
csc232::pd::Exam::Exam(double points) {

}
```

which then gives me the error,

"Constructor for 'csc232::pd::Exam' must explicitly initialize the base class 'csc232::pd::Assignment' which does not have a default constructor"

Issue # 2:

```
GradeType csc232::pd::Exam::getGrade() const {
return nullptr;
}
```

which gives me the error that GradeType is undefined.

If someone would be so kind as to point me in the right direction to fix those errors, I would greatly apperciate it. I am currently only working on implementing the base Assignment class, and Exam subclass. If you need more information, just let me know. (:

Comment: You're deriving from a base class that doesn't have a default constructor.  So call the constructor that it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is quite clear, just initialize the base class by calling the constructor.

```
csc232::pd::Exam::Exam(double points) : Assignment( points ) {
}
```

The second error is a result of not fully qualifying the return type `Grade`. `Grade` is a member of `csc232::pd` so you need to write:

```
csc232::pd::GradeType csc232::pd::Exam::getGrade() const {
  return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `GradeType` is supposed to be a template parameter of `Assignment`. So there is no such thing as `GradeType` in the context of class `Exam`. I can't say why in the diagram the overriding functions of derived classes substitute actual types for the function arguments but not the function return types....

Comment: @aschepler you are correct, GradeType is a template parameter of Assignment, so what would be a way to resolve this? For instance, should it just return a double as indicated in the UML Diagram?

Comment: @Cody Can you update your question so we can see the code you're working with?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes, one moment and I will include screenshots of the code I am working with.

Comment: @Cody You probably just need to put a `using grade_type = GradeType` inside `Assignment`. And then do `auto csc232::pd::Exam::getGrade() const -> grade_type {...}`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This is my most up to date code, if you could see if it lines up with the UML Diagram and if it does not, tell me where I need to make changes, it would be greatly appreciated (:

Comment: @Cody BTW don't post screen shots of code, just copy paste the code itself.

Comment: @0x499602D2 my apologies, still slightly learning how to navigate and use StackOverflow, thank you for telling me that though.

Comment: @Cody No problem. Did my previous comment help at all (about putting a type alias in `Assignment` and changing the signature of the function definition slightly)?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes! Thank you, I am now just working on resolving the issue of the exam constructor as I am still having Issue #1 as stated above. Any clues?

Comment: @Cody Does the code in my answer not work for you? It looks like it should. Are you still getting the same error after using my answer?